# Joining Population Data to Census Tract Shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I'm trying to create a population density map and I'm struggling with getting the population data to join correctly to a census tract shapefile.

Between the census tract shapefile and population data there is only one attribute shared between the two, the "geoid" column.

However, the amount of numbers in each "geoid" column differs and it's preventing me from creating the join that will allow me to make my map.

I'm pretty new to GIS.

[image]

Comment: Is that all your data in the spreadsheet? You may need to do some manipulation in the spreadsheet to make GEOIDs match. Since you are using excel, the LEFT(text, [num_chars]) or RIGHT(text,[num_chars]) functions come to mind....

Comment: Are the Excel file and the Shapefile supposed to "fit" together? Is it package so that it's possible to join the Excel to the Shapefile? If so, maybe you are not using the correct column for the join. I can see that there is GEO.id and GEO.id2. If both dataset are meant to be together, there is absolutely a common field in both datasets. The problem could be in the Excel then